# I have a .net 4.7 project but I can't add a reference to NetStandard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-standard

i have a project that is a .net 4.7. In the nuget manager, I install the .net standard 2.0 preview in this project, I can see the reference in the solution explorer, but I get an error that DateTime is definied in an assembly that is not referenced, that I have to add the reference to netstandard.dll.

I have added manually the reference to the netstandard.dll that I have in the package folder, but then I get the error that the System.boolean and other type are not definied.

So I would like to know how I could have a .net 4.7 project that use another project that is .net standard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until the automated tooling is shipped in an update to VS 2017 15.3 preview / .net core tooling 2.0.0 preview2, you need to include the NuGet package `NETStandard.Library.NETFramework` to get netstandard2.0 support in .NET Framework projects.

Comment: Note: At this point (07/10/2017) the package description says "This package is deprecated. To consume .NET Standard libraries from .NET Framework in VS2017 15.3, you only need the .NET Core 2.0 SDK installed. For VS 2015, you'll need NuGet client 3.6 or higher."
It might make sense to update your answer :-)